# it will reverse the plain text, replace whitespaces with ‘*’ then shift the alphabets of the plain text according to the encryption key

Tags: java, string, encryption

```
public class pppp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        s1=input.nextLine();
        char ch[]=new char[s1.length()];
        int x;
        x=input.nextInt();
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int h=0;
        for(i=s1.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
            ch[j]=s1.charAt(i);
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println(ch);
        for(i=0;i<s1.length();i++) {
            if(ch[i]==' ') {
                ch[i]='*';
            }
            else if((ch[i]+x)<122 && ch[i]!='*') {
                ch[i]+=x;
            }
            else if((ch[i]+x-'z')==1) {
                ch[i]='a';
            }
            else if(ch[i]+x-'z'>1) {
                ch[i]='a';
                ch[i]+=((ch[i]+x-'z')-1);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

when i try to print "megadeth" and give the key 7 according to which it will shift the characters in place of t, THIS '{' comes.

```
megadeth
7
htedagem
o{lkhnlt
```

It works for t now but if i write u instead of t i get N which is wrong.
This is the edited code.

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: What do you expect should have been printed instead?

Comment: a instead of {  because t+6 is z as t=116 in ascii value so i want it to count from a again if it exceeds z.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. How would you approach coding that?

Comment: I edited the code and wrote this, it worked for the t character of megadeth but if i write megadeuh i get wrong answer. I get N in place of u.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sir can you please check now?

Comment: Try figuring out why you get an N.  Consider testing with a string containing all letters

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you wanted to:

1. reverse your string
2. replace all occurences of a space character (`' '`) with a `'*'`
3. perform a Caesar key shift on the letters of the resulting string

Here is how you could do this using streams:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class pppp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        s1=input.nextLine();
        int x;
        x=input.nextInt();

        System.out.println(
            new StringBuilder(s1)
                .reverse().toString()
                .chars()
                .map(c -> c == ' ' ? '*' : c)
                .map(c -> {
                    if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                        char first = Character.isUpperCase(c) ? 'A' : 'a';
                        return first + (((c - first) + x) % 26);
                    }
                    else return c;
                })
                .mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char) c))
                .collect(Collectors.joining())
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant snippet that computes the shift:

```
char first = Character.isUpperCase(c) ? 'A' : 'a';
return first + (((c - first) + x) % 26);
```

---

Say you want to shift letter *t* by 7 places. Your result should be *a*.

To do this, lets first compute the index of the letter *t* in the alphabet (zero-based):

```
index = 't' - 'a' = 116 - 97 = 19
```

Next, add key to `index` modulo 26 to get the index of the letter that's shifted by key. In this case, the key is 7.

```
shiftIndex = (index + 7) % 26 = (19 +7) % 26 = 26 % 26 = 0
```

Finally, you can compute the shifted character like so:

```
result = 'a' + shiftIndex = 'a' + 0 = 'a'
```

And that's what my solution does, with the additional logic for upper case letters.